# What are toffee potatoes?

Tags: potatoes, toffee

I came across a reference to this in an article about Scandinavia.

They are apparently a regional delicacy.

Comment: Huh, I'm Danish and I've *never* heard of this...

Comment: Hi torbengb. It has to be brune kartofler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the toffee potatoes in the article must be *Brune kartofler*; the literal translation is "brown potatoes". They are simply small potatoes covered in caramelized sugar. The photo Ocaasi links to are potatoes gone terribly wrong. I think the photo caption is ironic.

They are a traditional side dish for any christmas meal with pork roast or duck. 
Here is a video that shows how they are made: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LYoJ14RIIhs.

The recipe is as follows:

- Boil small potatoes.
- Peel them.
- Distribute sugar evenly in the pan.
- Warm until the sugar caramelizes.
- Add butter in small pieces (amount of butter and sugar are equal).
- When the butter is incorporated add the potatoes.
- Distribute the caramel over the potates.
- After 10 minutes the potatoes are done.
- They should now have a nice layer of caramel around them.

Answer (score 4):

Research:

[Great Photo of Toffee Potatoes (TravelBlog.com)](http://www.travelblog.org/Photos/595334)

"Her Danish vegetarian equivalent of the Sunday roast is a decadent dish she calls mushroom pate. It's made with rice, mushrooms, onions, garlic, thyme, cream and eggs, all baked in the oven and served with warm pickled red cabbage, carrot batons **and the most delicious toffee potatoes**." [NZherald.com](http://www.nzherald.co.nz/food/news/article.cfm?c_id=206&objectid=10663066)

"When we were in Xian, the breakfast offerings included congee with corn, baked tofu with rice syrup, vegetable flied rice, and a wide assortment of regional teas. One unique tea tasted and looked just like spinach. On the way to see an archeological dig, we joined 10 tour buses of Chinese school children at a 'luncheon lodge' **and were served toffee potatoes (sweet potatoes served with caramelized rice sugar)**, red pepper flied cabbage, rice bundles, braised gluten with straw mushrooms, and quickly-braised greens with garlic." [Vegeterian Journal](http://findarticles.com/p/articles/mi_m0FDE/is_4_24/ai_n15788130/)

"The title of the blog indicates that I have found a new favourite food here and I ate about .5 kg of it at supper. **In Chinese restaurants in England we have toffee banana or apple- here they have toffee potato. It sounds a strange combination, but is delicious and great energy food...**" [Tuktotheroad](http://tuktotheroad.blogspot.com/2006_06_01_archive.html)

Recipe links:

- [Epicurious](http://www.epicurious.com/recipes/food/views/Caramelized-Potatoes-237664)
- [Group Recipes](http://www.grouprecipes.com/82847/danish-caramelized-potatoes.html)

Comment: The NZ Herald article is the one I read. It sounds to me that they are similar to toffee apples except that potatoes are used?

Comment: Yeah, they look like a dessert/sweet side dish.  They reminded me of an American holiday side-dish, sweet-potatoes with marshmallow on top.  It's delicious; I can't imagine this is bad either.

Comment: Looks like there are plenty of google hits for danish potatoes, caramel potatoes, caramelized potatoes... pretty similar recipes, e.g. http://www.epicurious.com/recipes/food/views/Caramelized-Potatoes-237664 or http://www.grouprecipes.com/82847/danish-caramelized-potatoes.html

Answer (score 1):

A great Asian delicacy

Had these the other night. Notice the fine candy thread off to the right. It is served hot, so as you chopstick up a piece you dip it into a bowl of cold water to cool the candy off before you eat it. Yum!!!

This is actually sweet potato (kumara) but essentially the same dish

[image]

Comment: Oh... I haven't had kumara in almost 3 years... that's one (of many) thing I miss of NZ :)